# Android CTS How to extend the shell-timeout value

Tags: android, shell, android-7.1-nougat, cts

I'm getting the following warning at the beginning of the run of some of the modules:

> W/InstrumentationTest: shell-timeout should be larger than test-timeout 900000; NOTE: extending shell-timeout to 990000, please consider fixing this!

I'm using the [android-cts-7.1_r6](https://source.android.com/compatibility/cts/downloads#android-71), how to extend the `shell-timeout` value?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to add export TMOUT= to your .bashrc file.

Answer (score 0):

`shell-timeout` and `test-timeout` are values defined in CTS config files. These configuration files are shipped with CTS and (I assume) not to be edited.

I believe you can simply **ignore this warning**.

Here a quick list of the config files:

```
$ grep -REI "shell-timeout|test-timeout" | cut -d':' -f1 | uniq
testcases/CtsSimpleCpuTestCases.config
testcases/CtsFileSystemTestCases.config
testcases/CtsAslrMallocTestCases.config
testcases/CtsMediaTestCases.config
testcases/CtsUiDeviceTestCases.config
testcases/CtsOpenGlPerf2TestCases.config
testcases/CtsMediaStressTestCases.config
testcases/CtsVideoTestCases.config
testcases/CtsSecurityTestCases.config
testcases/CtsCameraTestCases.config
testcases/CtsTvProviderTestCases.config
testcases/CtsLibcoreOjTestCases.config
testcases/CtsKeystoreTestCases.config
testcases/CtsLibcoreTestCases.config
testcases/CtsTvTestCases.config
testcases/CtsLibcoreOkHttpTestCases.config
testcases/CtsHardwareTestCases.config
```